# smpt.sendmail thow x509: certificate signed by unknown authority on windows

Tags: go, smtp

I try send mail using smtp package on windows host, but I got this error "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority".

Certificate that using mail server is valid.

How can I understand that this is due to the fact that the certificate store is configured incorrectly.

But I didn't find any information on how to do it.

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/mail"
    "net/smtp"
)

// StartTLS Email Example

func main() {

    from := mail.Address{"", "examplt@email.com"}
    to := mail.Address{"", "alhaos@gmail.com"}
    subj := "This is the email subject"
    body := "This is an example body.\n With two lines."

    // Setup headers
    headers := make(map[string]string)
    headers["From"] = from.String()
    headers["To"] = to.String()
    headers["Subject"] = subj

    // Setup message
    message := ""
    for k, v := range headers {
        message += fmt.Sprintf("%s: %s\r\n", k, v)
    }
    message += "\r\n" + body

    // Connect to the SMTP Server
    servername := "MyServer:587"

    host, _, _ := net.SplitHostPort(servername)

    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", "username", "pass", host)

    // TLS config
    tlsconfig := &tls.Config{
        // InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        ServerName: host,
    }

    c, err := smtp.Dial(servername)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    c.StartTLS(tlsconfig)

    // Auth
    if err = c.Auth(auth); err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    // To && From
    if err = c.Mail(from.Address); err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    if err = c.Rcpt(to.Address); err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    // Data
    w, err := c.Data()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    _, err = w.Write([]byte(message))
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    err = w.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    c.Quit()

}
```

Comment: *"Certificate that using mail server is valid."* - how do you know, how did you check? Make sure that a) it is not expired b) the subject alternatives name match the domain you access c) all necessary intermediate certificates are provided.

Comment: > how do you know, how did you check? yes i can see in via web interface

Comment: What exactly do you see there which makes you sure that a, b and c from my last comment are met? Are you sure you are looking at the certificate for port 587, not for example for the web server on port 443 - which might be different?